# Save data to a database from a multi-page form Wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress

how to save data to a database from a multi-page form using sessions in wordpress?

```
session_start();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
    $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;
}
extract($_SESSION['post']);
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    extract($_SESSION['post']);
    //global $wpdb;
    //$wpdb->insert("tablename", array("data" => $_SESSION["data"], array("%s"));
    include 'dbconnect.php';
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tablename ( data ) VALUES ( '{$data}' )";
        $conn ->exec($sql);
    }
        catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
        $conn = null;
        session_destroy();
    }
```

Trying to save a multi-page form to a database. I have no issues saving a single page form. However, once I try to use $_SESSION it will no longer save the data.
Thank you in advance
UPDATE: I could not get it to work using $wpdb; but it works just fine using PDO.

Comment: You either save it a bit at a time or save it when you have it all. So which of those have you tried so far

Comment: The idea is to save everything at the end

Comment: Are the pages identical ??

Comment: why do people think that images of code is easier? it isn't and it doesn't help your cause. If you can't add more text and to identify the problem you're having, then don't count on many to help or stay. I have visited and left.

Comment: Fred, its the first time i ask a question, so i am not sure what is the best format to ask.

Comment: xyious, the idea is to have 4 pages with different questions, but right now i am trying to link the first 2 to the database. i have no issue linking just one page. so i am guessing the mistake i am making is with the $_SESSION

Comment: Dont start the session in functions. Start it as the first thing the Main code block does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would generate the second page's form with hidden inputs with the values you get from the first form. Then save all the values to the database after checking them in the 2nd form.

Answer (score 0):

I would use three tables in your database. One with all clients that took part in the survey with very little information (like a timestamp, name or sth), one with all questions (question text, page they are listed on etc) and a third one with the userID and quesionID and the answer. This construct is contra-intuitive for debugging but is still the better option.

For example can you just issue `SELECT * FROM questions WHERE page=2` and you get all the questions on page two. 
But the big advantage for you here is that you can safe the answers to the answer-table independently from the other answers.

You can access all answers by a particular user by `SELECT * FROM answers WHERE uid=5` or all answers for a certain question.

Using this database structure is more versatile than cramming every bit of information into one big table.

I can give you more detailed information or code if you need it.